# Pressing twice on a Jbutton

Tags: java, swing

I am a beginner in GUI programming and I am working on a project with a different kind of button.

For one of my Jbutton, when pressed it calls another frame that performs a task.
However, that frame goes on the background when I am working on the main frame.
When you press again the button for the second time a null pointer error is generated. 
I want to be able to just bring back the frame that is in the background when the button is pressed for the second time.

```
        changecontrastB.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {


                // calls the contrast adjuster function 
                ContrastAdjuster mycontrast= new ContrastAdjuster();
                // running that function which brings that frame forward
                mycontrast.run("Brightness/Contrast...");

                mycontrast.setVisible(true);

                if (changecontrastB.isSelected() && mycontrast.isVisible()==false )
                {
                    changecontrastB.setEnabled(false);
                    mycontrast.setVisible(true);

                }
            }
        });
```

changecontrastB is my actual Jbuton.

Comment: Stack trace for the NPE would help a lot.

Comment: "that frame goes on the background"  do you mean looses focus ? You nay want to use `JDailog` as second frame, and set its modality. For more help plost [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

Do the following:

1. In the class with the button, create a member variable of type JFrame:

   JFrame frame = null;
2. In the action listener called from the button, include an if like this (you need to adapt it to your class names):

   if (frame = null) 
      frame = new MyFrame(); //Other initializations might be needed too.
    else 
      frame.toFront();